# Move map then show dialog

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to move map and then need to show dialog. Following code show dialog and then map gets move which is exactly opposite behavior.

```
function showDetails(property_id)
{
    map.panBy(300,0);           
    sleep(3000);            
    window.showModalDialog("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/add_property_from_map/"+18+"/"+73);
}

function sleep(ms)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dr. Molle points out. Your sleep() function is blocking all access to any other code being run. Use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function. Something like this:

```
function showDetails(property_id)
{
    map.panBy(300,0);           
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        window.showModalDialog("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/add_property_from_map/"+18+"/"+73);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sleep-function blocks the browser as long as it's running(even the panning of the map will be blocked). Use `window.setTimeout()` to accomplish a delay between panning and the dialog.